# In which directory should I put my server program?

Tags: server

I'm maintaining a small server-side project on a ubuntu 14.04 server.
The server program is in my home directory till now, and I want to move it to a public location so that someone else could take over my work.

Where should I put the server program?
Is /srv a good choice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can put into /var/www folder